# jquery - clone td, prepend, and change new td to div

Tags: jquery, clone, prepend, replacewith

I'm successfully cloning a series of `<td>`s and placing them within another series of `<td>`s, but when I try to replaceWith the new `<td>`s with `<divs>`, the `<td>`s are being stripped away, not replaced.

Basically, I'm taking the first set of `<td>`s here and prepending a clone of each within the second set of `<td>`s respectively. This would be the HTML/DOM pre-clone:

```
<tr>
    <td class="weekTitles 1" nowrap="nowrap">Sun Jun 28</td>
    <td class="weekTitles 2" nowrap="nowrap">Mon Jun 29</td>
    <td class="weekTitles 3" nowrap="nowrap">Tue Jun 30</td>
    <td class="weekTitles 4" nowrap="nowrap">Wed Jul 01</td>
    <td class="weekTitles 5" nowrap="nowrap">Thu Jul 02</td>
    <td class="weekTitles 6" nowrap="nowrap">Fri Jul 03</td>
    <td class="weekTitles 7" nowrap="nowrap">Sat Jul 04</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="eventText" valign="top"></td>
    <td class="eventText" valign="top"></td>
    <td class="eventText" valign="top"></td>
    <td class="eventText" valign="top"></td>
    <td class="eventText" valign="top"></td>
    <td class="eventText" valign="top"></td>
    <td class="eventText" valign="top"></td>
</tr>
```

A snippet from the second sets of `<td>` shows cloning/prepending is working correctly:

```
<tr>
    <td class="eventText" valign="top">
        <td class="weekTitles 1" nowrap="nowrap" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">Sun Jun 28</td>
    </td>
    <td class="eventText" valign="top">
        <td class="weekTitles 2" nowrap="nowrap" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">Mon Jun 29</td>
    </td>
```

...etc...

And my javascript is working fine through the .css background color function (used as a test to see if I'm targeting new cloned element correctly), but once I get to the replaceWith, the new cloned inner `<td>`s are being stripped away as such:

```
<tr>
    <td class="eventText" valign="top">
        Sun Jun 28
    </td>
    <td class="eventText" valign="top">
        Mon Jun 29
    </td>
```

...etc...

When the desired result should look like this (but doesn't because my script is broken):

```
<tr>
    <td class="eventText" valign="top">
        <div class="weekTitles 1" nowrap="nowrap" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">Sun Jun 28</div>
    </td>
    <td class="eventText" valign="top">
        <div class="weekTitles 2" nowrap="nowrap" style="background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">Mon Jun 29</div>
    </td>
```

...etc...

Here's my script, working through the .css function but failing after that:

```
$('.page-calendar .bodyClass tr:nth-child(1) > td.weekTitles').each(function() {
         count = count + 1;
         //console.log(count);
         //console.log(this);
         $(this).clone().prependTo( $(this).closest('table').find('tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(' + count + ')') );
// below variable is how I am identifying new element
         var newElem = $('.page-calendar .bodyClass tr:nth-child(2) td.eventText:nth-child(' + count + ') td.weekTitles')[0];
         //console.log(newElem);
         $(newElem).css('background','red');
// this is where it breaks below, no replace of TD with DIV
         $(newElem).each(function (){
            $(this).replaceWith( $(this).html()
            .replace(/<td/gi, '<div')
            .replace(/<\/td>/gi, '</div>')
             );
         });
    });
```

In short, I think it all comes down to my failure to properly grasp how to write the "$(newElem).each..." function to replace the TDs with DIVs.  It's removing the TDs entirely instead of replacing them with DIVs.

Any and all pointers much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: The HTML you're attempting to generate is invalid - hence the problems. A `td` or a `div` cannot be a direct descendant of another `td`.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. I'm aware it's not proper to have a TD within a TD, and hence the desire to change the inner/improper TDs to DIVs.  Would a TD within a TD cause the function to fail?  It's not invalid to have a DIV within a TD, right?  If the nested TDs are causing the script to fail, then the TD to DIV replacement could happen before the prepend??  I've tried variations on that, too, to no avail.

Comment: It would probably be clearer if you could provide an example of the HTML output you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I did.  See the code under the line that reads, "When the desired result should look like this..."  It would be TR>TD>DIV instead of the cloned and prepended TR>TD>TD.  My replaceWith code is failing and leaving me with just TR>TD, losing the inner TD that should become a DIV.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to clone the elements - all you need to do is create a new `div` element and apply the `class` and `text` from the original to it.

Note that CSS styling should be applied via a stylesheet, not inline, and that the `nowrap` attribute is outdated. You should instead again use CSS, `white-space: nowrap`. Try this:

```
$('td.weekTitles').each(function(i) {
    $('<div />', {
        className: $(this).attr('class')
    }).text($(this).text()).appendTo('.eventText:eq(' + i + ')');
});
```

```css
.eventText div {
    background: red none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9d4hossw/)

Comment: That's awesome. So much simpler. So much more elegant. Thank you!